# Density of a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

How do I find the density of a given binary tree? I came across this interview question and not sure as to what they mean by density! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question conforms to the norms laid down by SO for the questions to be asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dense binary tree is close to perfect (it has close to `2^(h + 1) - 1 nodes)`. A sparse tree is  closer to a linked list (it has close to `h` nodes). `h` is the height of the tree where a single root node has height 0.

A simple measure of density could be:

```
(n - h)/(2^(h + 1) - h - 1)
```

I just made that formula up, so I don't know if it would suit your needs for an interview answer, but it'll give you 0 for a degenerate tree and 1 for a perfect tree.  It will give you numbers close to 1 for dense trees, and numbers close to 0 for sparse ones.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) has a lot of information on binary trees.

Answer (score 0):

In a binary trees, the number of nodes at each level falls within a range of values.
At level 0, there is 1 node, the root; at level 1 there can be 1 or 2 nodes.
At any level k, the number of nodes is in the range from 1 to 2k.
The number of nodes per level contributes to the density of the tree. Intuitively, density is a measure of the size of a tree (number of nodes) relative to the height of the tree.